# Automating with Ant on a server

Tags: java, ant

I have a ant file on the server-side, and from the client-side I need to execute it on the server, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute the ANT build script and targets from a servlet.

This article explains how: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/07/24/antauto.html?page=1

Answer (score 2):

SSH should work on any Unix system:

```
ssh gooner@host.example.com ant -f /home/gooner/build.xml
```

*Do not* use RSH - it's obsolete, and it's been replaced with the more secure SSH.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me how will I run this command from say a web page running on the client side

Comment: btw, i am running an apache server.

Comment: @Gooner just make a simple cgi in shell in that case, or do as Mads suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps overkill for your situation, but you might want to look at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). It is a Java build server with a web interface. It is relatively easy to [set up](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Use+Hudson) and [configure projects](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project), though you will need to run a servlet container on your server (such as Apache Tomcat).